# Mac SSD freezing & I/O error

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, freeze, io

6 months ago I've added a SSD (Samsung 840 Pro 512GB) on the back of the superdrive and enabled TRIM. It's still as fast as it was when I bought it.

Since some days my mac randomly freezes twice a day (can still move the mouse, but starting a app from the dock just keeps bouncing). When I look into the console after a freeze it shows 100's of I/O errors with sometime's another error of the app I was currently using in it.

Verify disk returns no errors, shows no beachball and is very fast (unlike other people's I/O errors).

Information:
Health status: 100%
Power on hours (just): 1413 hours
Temperature: 49 °C (after a 'freeze')

How can I get rid of the freeze's?

Comment: Can you show us some of the errors?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz while Google Chrome was started I've tried to startup iBooks and App Store that's why they are in the log, I think. http://i.imgur.com/oTkVkOQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded DriveDx and saw 10.000 CRC error's. After that I've replaced the cable between my SSD and my iMac (had to open it). And now it's fully working again.